# Split is producing an IndexError on one line while executing as expected on every other line when trying to rename columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, debugging, split, index-error

I have a dataset with a very larger number of columns formatted like `a.b.c.d.e.` My goal is to do two things. I would like to change the column name to 'c' I would also like to generate a dictionary for later use where 'c' maps to 'b.c' so I can change the names back at a later point. The full function I am using is below.

```py
def trim_col_names(df):

    cols = []
    string_matches = {}
    for col in df.columns[3:]:
        tokens = col.split('.')
        trimmed = tokens[2]
        cols.append(trimmed)
        colname = '.'.join(tokens[1:3])
        string_matches[trimmed] = colname
    df.columns = list(df.columns)[:3] + cols

    df_p = trim_col_names(df_p)
```

Tokens prints as expected `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` however I am getting the following error. `trimmed = tokens[2] IndexError: list index out of range`

Interestingly when I switched the order or the lines `trimmed = tokens[2]` and `colname = '.'.join(tokens[1:3])` so colname was executed first, the error still appeared on trimmed which makes me think the problem is isolated to this one line. I also use very similar lines in other functions within this code with no issue. What am I missing?

Here is a sample dataset. It is thousands of columns so I have only given a very small subset of data. If this is not sufficient I can provide a larger dataset.

```
X  Y  Z  tpm.293SLAM_rinderpest_infection_00hr.CH123.bhg.gh   tpm.293SLAM_rinderpest_infection_01hr.CH124.byl.gw  tpm.293SLAM_rinderpest_infection_02hr.CH125.lmg.ge

x  y  z                          2                                                2                                               4

x1 y1 z1                         3                                                8                                               2

x2 y2 z2                         4                                                5                                               7
```

I am trying to keep `CH123` as the column name and `293SLAM_rinderpest_infection_00hr.CH123` as the value it maps to in the dictioary.

Comment: Please [create a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `df.head(10).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard), [edit] the question, and paste the clipboard into a code block. The question should [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (e.g. code, data, errors) as text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The dataset is thousands of columns so I have recreated a smaller version and included it in the question.

Comment: Voted to close because I suspect your error is with bad data somewhere inside your dataset.    Perhaps putting `assert len(tokens) >= 2, print(tokens)` will help catch the issue for you.

Comment: @David If the error is just with bad data why does `colname = '.'.join(tokens[1:3])` not raise an error? This is joining together 1&2 where as trimmed is just selecting 2?

Comment: @keenan That's a range query so given `x = []` and `x[1:3]` that produces `[]`